# How can I check HSV value of pixel?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read HSV value of pixel. I wrote that code, but it is probably wrong. Can you help me with that? Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

```
img = new QImage(600,600,QImage::Format_RGB32);
img -> load("D:/1.jpg");
bits = img->bits();

int h = bits[0].hue();
int s = bits[1].saturation();
int v = bits[2].value();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform to QColor and use .toHsv

```
QColor color(bits[0],bits[1],bits[2]);
color.toHsv();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find it, I do it like that?
int h = color.hue;

Comment: try `color.hue()` it's a function.